# Magento 2 get availabe stock of product

Tags: magento2, stock, quantity

I need to display available quantity on product list and details page and other pages where product shows.

I extended product list class as below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Tm\Stockinfo\Block\Product\Stockqty" />
</config>
```

And here i write code in extended block

```
<?php

 namespace Tm\Stockinfo\Block\Product;


class Stockqty extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct {

    protected  $_stockState;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState,
            array $data = []

        )
        {
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
            $this->_stockState = $stockState;
        }




    public function getStockQty($product) {


       return $this->stockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    }

}
```

Then i am getting below error

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
>   Tm\Stockinfo\Block\Product\Stockqty::__construct() must implement
>   interface Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface, array
>   given, called in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\amit\mage222\generated\code\Tm\Stockinfo\Block\Product\Stockqty\Interceptor.php
>   on line 14 and defined in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\amit\mage222\app\code\Tm\Stockinfo\Block\Product\Stockqty.php:10
>   Stack trace: #0
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\amit\mage222\generated\code\Tm\Stockinfo\Block\Product\Stockqty\Interceptor.php(14):
>   Tm\Stockinfo\Block\Product\Stockqty->__construct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context),
>   Array) #1
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\amit\mage222\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(111):
>   Tm\Stockinfo\Block\Product\Stockqty\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context),
>   Array) #2
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\amit\mage222\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(66):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Tm\Stockinfo\
>   in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\amit\mage222\app\code\Tm\Stockinfo\Block\Product\Stockqty.php
>   on line 10

=========================== Edit question ===================================

And here layout xml  "\app\code\Tm\Stockinfo\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceContainer name="product.info.price">
            <container name="quantity_show" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="show_quantity" after="product.price.final">
               <block class="Tm\Stockinfo\Block\Product\Stockqty" name="stockinfo_showstock" template="Tm_Stockinfo::stockinfo_index_index.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I am trying to inject "\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface" class but due to listproduct construct method it gives error. I know i can use same construct Listproduct block but it is not good to go in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the StockRegistryInterface, Also you have to see the extended class and pass all needed parameters to the parent constructor, in your class you extended  this class

**=>\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct**

So you have to pass his parameters,

Try this code.

```
 <?php
namespace Tm\Stockinfo\Block\Product;

class Stockqty extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{

    protected $_stockRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        array $data = [])
    {
            parent::__construct(
                $context,
                $postDataHelper,
                $layerResolver,
                $categoryRepository,
                $urlHelper,
                $data
                );
        $this->_stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }

    public function getStockQty(
        $product)
    {
        $stockitem = $this->_stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId(),
            $product->getStore()
                ->getWebsiteId());
        $qtyStock = $stockitem->getData("qty");
        return $qtyStock;
    }
}
```

Please note that this code working on Magento 2.2.3, So you need to check the parent class in your version

Answer (score 1):

You can use **StockItemRepository** instead

```
<?php
namespace Tm\Stockinfo\Block\Product;
class Stockqty extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_stockItemRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getStockItem($productId)
    {
        return $this->_stockItemRepository->get($productId);
    }
}
?>
```

and call on template like this :

```
$_productStk = $block->getStockItem($_product->getId());

echo $_productStk->getQty();
echo $_productStk->getIsInStock();
```

Or you can use this directly in template ( not recommended but just in case )

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface');
    echo $StockState->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Naveed, Please check my editable section. how can i load product or get  product id. I am using "Tm_Stockinfo::stockinfo_index_index.phtml"

Comment: could you share your template code ?

Comment: Hi naveed, apologize, I add nothing in template. it is just a blank file. That would be next task for me